Super hero cartoon with a main character with no powers in a school full of heroes
It's a super hero cartoon about a kid with no powers in a school full of super heroes with powers. His friends also have powers (and I'm pretty sure one of them was a goth girl, she became the queen of slugs in one episode)
The main character's hero costume was a cape and an underwear outside of his pants and the recurring villain was a janitor with a robot minion that looks like it was made with house objects.
Every time he becomes evil he just wears a cape.
At first I thought it was World of Quest because the art style was pretty similar, but no it wasn't.

You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Supernormal


In the ordinary city of Crumptonville can be found a school for superheroes! Sure, the students wear Spandex and study Death Traps and Doomsday Machines, but they still have all the problems normal kids have at normal schools. There are super-achievers and super-slackers, super-nerds and super-jocks… there's even a teacher's pet - but it lives in the basement, and eats cats! SuperNormal follows the adventures of four of the, er, less promising students at the school. There’s Changerella - a peace-loving shape-shifter who thinks the world would be happier with more flowers, love and pink stuff. The Brass Butt (BB to his friends) - he's not too bright, but is super strong and uses his mighty and shiny brass butt to fight the forces of evil! Buzz Girl - a sarcastic four-armed girl who possesses a multitude of powers from the insect world... and a weakness for porch lights! And Eric Normal. An ordinary boy with no superpowers whatsoever. Yet through a combination of sheer good luck and a little dash of common sense, he was able to get through the school’s combination obstacle course/entrance exam. It's here that brave, enthusiastic and earnest Eric Normal and his friends will learn what it really means to be heroes, with or without superpowers!

I found the show mentioned in the Western Animation section of The Team Normal on TV Tropes. The plotline and the underwear on the outside matched up.
Teaser




dude thats the show thank you very much you actually found it thank you although the characters looked different than i remembered but most of my childhood cartoons looked different in my memories thank you
